# I have to Read footer of a file and store it into a arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a GMF file. Its last 9 lines are to be considered as footer. The fast line of footer Starts with "Footer" and last line Ends with "End of file".

So far I have written this

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                    if(headcount<11)
                    {
                        HeaderArray.add(sCurrentLine);
                        headcount++;
                        System.out.println("Header["+headcount+"]");
                        System.out.println("sCurrentLine"+sCurrentLine);
                    }
                    else if( headcount>10 &&(sCurrentLine.startsWith("Rerate"))) {


                                RecordsArray.add(sCurrentLine);
                                headcount++;
                                System.out.println("Records");
                                System.out.println("Record"+sCurrentLine);

                    }
                    else if(sCurrentLine.startsWith("Footer"))
                    {   
                            while(footerFlag!="End_of_file:")
                            {

                                FooterArray.add(sCurrentLine);
                                footerFlag=br.readLine();
                                sCurrentLine=footerFlag;
                                System.out.println("Footer");
                                System.out.println("Footer"+sCurrentLine);


                            }
                    }

            }
```

But this code only goes into an infinite loop. I need all 9 lines of footers in FooterArray. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change `while(footerFlag!="End_of_file:")` to `while(!footerFlag.equals("End_of_file:"))`  and see what will happen?

Comment: Make this `while(!"End_of_file:".equals(footerFlag))` - footerFlag is probably unitialized or null at this point. And, by the way, footerFlag appears to be useless in this code - but I agree we do not have the full code here.

Answer (score 0):

If third party libraries are an option for you the [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) project has a class called [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html) that will allow you to retrieve the footer of your file with minimal fuss.

I agree with @Anton that the `.equals()` method is the way to go to if you're trying to locate the EOF token.  The way you've written your conditional statement is to see if the variable `footerFlag` has the exact memory location as the String literal `"End_of_file:"`, which will never evaluate to `true`.